# mod_rewrite - detect a GET Request URL and render index.php

Tags: mod-rewrite

Sorry for the 1000000 topic on this, but I've been trying and searching for hours and couldn't find anything.

Basically, I have already used mod_rewrite to allow someone to type in www.example.com/web/chat/tf/

and that would go to
www.example.com/web/index.php?mode=chat&game=tf

But now I need to block people from actually typing in the GET request URL (the second one), and make it the friendly one to prevent duplicate pointers. So really, if anyone types in index.php?mode=

I want it to reroute to simply index.php

Here's what I've tried (none of it has worked)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mode.*
RewriteRule .* index.php

RewriteRule ^index.php\?.*$ index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} mode.*
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mode=
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

So that for the given URL :

```
http://www.example.com/web/index.php?mode=chat&game=tf
```

It will return :

```
http://www.example.com/web/index.php
```